# What exactly is targetSdkVersion?

Tags: android

I know that `targetSdkVersion` is the "highest SDK version, your app is known to work with", but what is the point? I set my `targetSdkVersion` 22, and my app runs fine on an api 25 device. Is it not meant to prevent installation on further api versions? If no, then what is it meant for?

Comment: Read: [targetSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target)

Comment: If you raise target to 25 and run again on API 25 device it may (and considering all the doze stuff it will) break.

Answer (score 7):

> android:targetSdkVersion An integer designating the API Level that the
>   application targets. If not set, the default value equals that given
>   to minSdkVersion. This attribute informs the system that you have
>   tested against the target version and the system should not enable any
>   compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility
>   with the target version. The application is still able to run on older
>   versions (down to minSdkVersion).
>
> As Android evolves with each new version, some behaviors and even
>   appearances might change. However, if the API level of the platform is
>   higher than the version declared by your app's targetSdkVersion, the
>   system may enable compatibility behaviors to ensure that your app
>   continues to work the way you expect. You can disable such
>   compatibility behaviors by specifying targetSdkVersion to match the
>   API level of the platform on which it's running. For example, setting
>   this value to "11" or higher allows the system to apply a new default
>   theme (Holo) to your app when running on Android 3.0 or higher and
>   also disables screen compatibility mode when running on larger screens
>   (because support for API level 11 implicitly supports larger screens).
>
> There are many compatibility behaviors that the system may enable
>   based on the value you set for this attribute. Several of these
>   behaviors are described by the corresponding platform versions in the
>   Build.VERSION_CODES reference.
>
> To maintain your application along with each Android release, you
>   should increase the value of this attribute to match the latest API
>   level, then thoroughly test your application on the corresponding
>   platform version.
>
> Introduced in: API Level 4

Sorry for just posting straight from Android.com but it gives a clear signal of what it does.

Answer (score 0):

It is the one you are developing for. App can work on higher API as well. But it is the one used for rendering layout etc.